# Testing For All Non-collided Tiles in XNA

Tags: c#, foreach, xna, collision-detection

I'm currently writing a platforming game in XNA.
My collision testing currently operates by testing the bounding box of the player with every tile's bounding box by running through a foreach loop. However, I can't figure out how to test whether the player is NOT touching any blocks.

How would I run through my array and test for if they player isn't touching any blocks so that I can check if he is in mid air? Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

/////////////////////////////////////

My collision code is

```
    if (personRectangle.TouchTopOf(newRectangle))
    {
         onGround = true;
         test = false;
         test2 = true;
    }
```

The corresponding bool test is

```
    public static bool TouchTopOf(this Rectangle r1, Rectangle r2)
    {
        return (r1.Bottom >= r2.Top - 1 &&
                r1.Bottom <= r2.Top + (r2.Height / 2) &&
                r1.Right >= r2.Left + (r2.Width / 5) &&
                r1.Left <= r2.Right - (r2.Width / 5));
    }
```

And this piece of code tests collision in the Game1.cs update.

```
        foreach (CollisionTiles tile in map.CollisionTiles)
            player.Collision(tile.Rectangle);
```

Which is a list of tiles in my map class

```
    private List<CollisionTiles> collisionTiles = new List<CollisionTiles>();
```

Answer (score 3):

XNA Rectangles have a built-in intersects method:

```
if (rect1.Intersects(rect2)){
...
}
```

just loop through the tile rectangles and call intersects on each one. To make it more efficient you should map the player coords onto world coords and determine the tiles nearest to the player, doing this you can narrow down the number of tiles you need to loop over.

EDIT: for clarification, you could have:

```
bool collision=false;
foreach (CollisionTiles tile in map.CollisionTiles) {
    if(personRectangle.Intersects(tile.Rectangle)) {
        collision =true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Then if collision is true you know there was a collision somewhere.

Comment: I'm not sure if I get what you mean. I'm currently using the rectangle.Top, etc. methods for testing boundaries. But it tests every block and gets confused because it's touching some blocks but not others, resulting in both if(true) and else(false) being triggered. I'm looking to have it test whether it's not touching ANY  block...

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a reason not to, keep it simple. Just keep track of how many things you collided with. If your count ends up being 0 then you didn't collide with anything.

Without worrying about modifying / optimizing any of the code you have, it could be something like:

```
int touchedCount = 0;
foreach (CollisionTiles tile in map.CollisionTiles)
{
        if (player.Collision(tile.Rectangle))
        {
             touchedCount++;
        }
}

if (touchedCount == 0)
{
    //You did not collide with anything
}
```

Then inside your collision method do something similar to keep track of your checks and if you collided at all. This would probably be easiest using Rectangle.Intersects as the other answer suggests.

Comment: Your code is incorrect, if you don't collide with anything touchCount will be non zero. You could possibly put the increment inside the if but collisions on other sides will not be detected

Comment: Hah. Even with that thought my code was wrong. I see what you mean now. I believe my edit still fixed the problem. Thanks again!